# Is it Possible to ask a self study question on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

Being sidetracked in my career i wish to learn computer sciences. I dont have the time or resources to get a four year degree. I want to find the answers related to gathering good resources on certain subjects.
Books to learn mac terminal, assembly, computer architecture, etc..
 Is it ok to ask such questions there? If not is there another site i can go to and solve my doubts?

Comment: Not really, no - they'd be closed as "primarily opinion based" on the vast majority of (if not all) Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Questions that ask for resources are not on-topic on any Stack Exchange sites.  Now once you start getting involved and have specific questions about specific items, then you can likely find a Stack Exchange site to help you, but which one depends on the questions you might have.

Comment: the type of questions you can and can't ask are defined in each exchange site's help centres

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it ok to ask such questions there?

No, it isn't. Asking for off-site resources is specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow, Programmers and most of the Stack Exchange network (with a few sites that do allow them but with restrictions).

We actually have an off-topic close reason on Stack Overflow just for these kinds of questions:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

There are many, many, many programming forums that you can ask on. Just not Stack Exchange sites.

---

Now, if, during your studies, you have a **specific** programming question, with code (and you explain where you are stuck, what you tried etc...), that would be great to see on Stack Overflow (provided you also searched first and it is not a duplicate).